# Get Font.Weight in iOS 14

Tags: swift, uikit, ios13, ios14, uifont

In iOS 13 and low I got Font.Weight using this extension for UIFont

```
var weight: UIFont.Weight {
    guard let traits = fontDescriptor.object(forKey: .traits) as? [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey: Any], let weightValue = traits[.weight] as? CGFloat else { return .regular }
    let weight = UIFont.Weight(rawValue: weightValue)
    return weight
}
```

But since iOS 14 weightValue is wrong.
For example:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 21)
print(font?.weight.rawValue)
print(font?.weight == .bold)
```

iOS 14 - 0.40000000000000002 false

iOS 13 - 0.40000000596046448 true

Anybody faced with it?

Comment: Seems like iOS 14+ is more precise rather then "wrong"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is in fact expected to be inaccurate after a high number of decimal places (16 in this case). Floats are calculated via the IEEE 754 standard for Single-Precision Floating-Point arithmetic. The original standard was only accurate up to [7 decimal places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for integers between 4 and 6, but this has iteratively improved since the original, for example in 2019 and 2020 (see [here](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/754-1985.html) for details).

What you see is probably the effect of conditional casting. The conversion from `Float` to `CGFloat` loses precision.